# MySQl need to add a column to the existing query / print the group name in the added column

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a query like this

```
SELECT us.recNo, 
       CONCAT(us.firstname, ' ',us.lastname) AS fullname, 
       max(dy.date) AS diarydate
FROM users us LEFT JOIN diary dy ON us.recNo = dy.clientID AND dy.date >= 
       (SELECT max(DATE(dateTime)) 
       FROM `history` 
       WHERE userID=us.managerID) OR dy.date is NULL
WHERE us.managerID =  6  and us.accountStatus = 2 and us.securityGroup = 50
GROUP BY us.recNo, fullname
ORDER BY diarydate DESC, fullname
```

So i have two groups, one group by date(if they have any diary entry date), then group the rest(NULL).

I need to use optgroup in the dropdown box using php. For that i need to have an extra column which says, which group the record belongs to, for example

```
recNo   fullname    diarydate   group
```

2      LucyLabrond  23/11/13    DiaryGroup

3      Emily        24/12/13    DiaryGroup

4      Vincus       Null        NoDiary

5      Matt         Null        NoDiary

Please help me group this.

Comment: you could look into using a `CASE...WHEN` type approach

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must use a `case` clause. Try this:

```
SELECT us.recNo, 
       CONCAT(us.firstname, ' ',us.lastname) AS fullname, 
       max(dy.date) AS diarydate,
       case when MAX(dy.date) IS NOT NULL then 'DiaryGroup' else 'NoDiary' end as group
FROM users us LEFT JOIN diary dy ON us.recNo = dy.clientID AND dy.date >= 
       (SELECT max(DATE(dateTime)) 
       FROM `history` 
       WHERE userID=us.managerID) OR dy.date is NULL
WHERE us.managerID =  6  and us.accountStatus = 2 and us.securityGroup = 50
GROUP BY us.recNo, fullname
ORDER BY diarydate DESC, fullname
```